# How should I spell the name of the ruling: 30%-ruling or 30% ruling?

Tags: spelling

The Dutch expat tax regime is commonly referred to as: '30%-ruling'. Or should this be spelled '30% ruling' without the dash?

Comment: What does 30% ruling mean? That might help to decipher which is best.

Comment: The ruling allows for the employee to receive 30% of his/her remuneration as a tax free allowance.
These sentences are typically used:

The 30% ruling provides a tax free allowance (30% allowance) which is deemed to cover all so-called extraterritorial costs. Extraterritorial costs are defined as the extra costs for staying outside of the country of origin.

Application of the 30% ruling gives rise to a substantial increase in net salary for the employee and substantial reduction of employer’s costs.

Comment: In that case I agree with the answer that no hyphen is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be a dash unless the phrase is being used attributively, as in *the parliament debated new 30%-ruling legislation yesterday.*

There seems to be a recent trend toward increased hyphenation of compound nouns like this, but since I live in Europe it's difficult to get a good sense of the extent to which this perception is based on the writing of non-native speakers (many of whom would write these as one word in their native language) and how much of the trend is genuinely found among native speakers.

Comment: I think any "trend toward increased hyphenation of compound nouns" simply reflects the tendency for certain word-pairs (word pairs, [wordpairs](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wordpairs%22)) to change from being written as two words, through hyphenation to eventual *single-word* status. Per that link, the single-word form for ***wordpairs*** already has some currency, but I'm sure that will never happen with ***singlewords***. My hyphenated ***single-word** status* is a special case where the (singular) two-word form is being used ***adjectivally***.